# Automake linking for multiple PROGRAMS

Tags: build, automake

I'm using Autotools for building my project that contains multiple binaries (repo with commandline tools).

How can I link some of libraries to all of the programs and some other libraries only to particular programs?

Example:
My Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS= prog1 prog2
prog1_SOURCES=prog1.cpp
prog2_SOURCES=prog2.cpp

prog1_LDADD= -llib-only-for-prog1

LDADD=-llib-for-all-projects      # this does not work
#AM_LDFLAGS=-llib-for-all-projects      # this does not work either
#LINK=-llib-for-all-projects      # this does not work either
```

I want `prog1` to be linked against `-llib-only-for-prog1` and `-llib-for-all-projects` 
 while `prog2` - only against `-llib-for-all-projects`.

How can I achieve that with autotools?

Comment: You might also find: [`AM_DEFAULT_SOURCE_EXT = .cpp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Default-_005fSOURCES) useful here.

Comment: @BrettHale Thanks. I have many programs in my repo, but only some use more sources than one. I understand that this will work if I don't specify the `<name>_SOURCES` and if I do- it will overwrite, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you add `LDADD` for a speficic program (`prog1_LDADD`) it will ignore the common `LDADD` options.

The following works for me:

```
bin_PROGRAMS=prog1 prog2 prog3
prog1_SOURCES=prog1.c
prog2_SOURCES=prog2.c
prog3_SOURCES=prog3.c

LDADD=-llib-for-all-projects
prog1_LDADD=-llib-only-for-prog1 $(LDADD)
```

note the extra `$(LDADD`) in the `prog1_LDADD`-line.

Comment: Ok. I did not know that `prog1_LDADD` overwrites the `LDADD`. This helps me. Thanks